# How can I find the presample states of an AR model?

Tags: time-series

I have a question about the presample states of an ARMA model. Let assume that we have an AR(2) model $$x_t=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1x_{t-1} +\alpha_2x_{t-2}.  $$

If $t=1, t=2$, then $x_1,x_2$ states are = ??.

I am using Matlab and the program has a function which says the following:

> If your model is stable:
>
> The model is AR-stable and without a regression component, so compute 
>     the unconditional (i.e., long-run) mean of the y(t) process directly 
>     from the parameters of the model and use it to initialize any required 
>     presample observations.
>
> If your model is not stable:
>
> The model is not AR-stable, and so a long-run mean of the y(t) process 
>     cannot be calculated from the model. The following simply assumes zeros 
>     for any required presample observations for y(t).

Could somenone explain this to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just use that $x_t=0\,\forall\, t<1$. So for $t=1$ you get:

$$
x_1=\alpha_0
$$

and for $t=2$

$$
x_2=\alpha_0+\alpha_1x_1=\alpha_0(1+\alpha_1).
$$